# Map function renders first react element differently while using tailwind's utility classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind for CSS in my project and I map over a React button element like this:

```
    <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center space-x-1 space-y-1">
        {domains.map((domain, index) => {
          return (
            <Button
              key={index}
              bgColor="transparent"
              hoverEffect="blue-500"
              textColor="gray-700"
              textHover="white"
              boarder="blue-500"
              boarderHover="blue-500"
              otherClasses="text-xs block rounded-full px-4"
              selcted="blue-500"
              buttonTitle={domain}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

Edit 1: Here is the button component

```
export const Button = ({
  bgColor,
  hoverEffect,
  textColor,
  textHover,
  boarder,
  boarderHover,
  otherClasses,
  buttonTitle,
  selcted,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="block">
        <button
          className={
            `bg-${bgColor} ${hoverEffect && `hover:bg-${hoverEffect}`}
          text-${textColor} ${textHover && `hover:text-${textHover}`}
          border border-${boarder} hover:border-${boarderHover} ${otherClasses}` +
            ` lg:focus:bg-${selcted ?? selcted} lg:focus:text-${textHover}`
          }
        >
          {buttonTitle}
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

If I render this code it returns something like this:
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XqxRQ6bUTSQqZTJVqbv-c9Rs4hXy01J2/view?usp=sharing)

The first item in the map gets a different orientation when I use flex or grid. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. If I manually render several times it renders properly.

Comment: Photo not loading, can you try to change key={index} to key={domain}

Comment: @iunfixit (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XqxRQ6bUTSQqZTJVqbv-c9Rs4hXy01J2/view?usp=sharing) try this, and changing it to key ={domain} has no effect as such.

Comment: Is the `Button` component from a library or did you create it? Could you share the name of the library or the code for that component if it's custom?

Comment: I created using Tailwind CSS, I will attach the Button component also here. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Guys Sorry for the late update. but I found out this is some issue with the vertical space option in tailwind CSS.

```
class= "space-y-6"
```

something similar to this. if you are using this try removing this. or find a workaround, it should work.